# Array filtering on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have this code, which filters my data. I'm asking me, if there is a way not to filter each field (`id`, `mandant`, `zonenlogik`...) explicitly.
Maybe there is a more smooth way to set the filter on all fields without calling them explicitly?

```
let filteredList = this.state.freights.filter((freight) => {

    if (freight.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return freight;
    }
    if (freight.mandant.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return freight;
    }
    if (freight.zonenlogik.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return freight;
    }
    if (freight.frachtart_nr.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return freight;
    }
    if (freight.transportart_nr.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return freight;
    }
    if (freight.spedit_nr.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return freight;
    }
    if (freight.spedit2_nr.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return freight;
    }
    if (freight.lager_nr.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        return freight;
    }
});
```

Comment: To simplify the codes, first you can reuse the variables like `this.state.search.toLowerCase()`. Also, you can group the similar logic with a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fetch the object values using `Object.values()` and then loop over those to check whether a substring is present in the string and then return the filtered object

```
let filteredList = this.state.freights.filter((freight) => {
    let search = this.state.search.toLowerCase();
    var values = Object.values(freight);
    var flag = false
    values.forEach((val) => {
      if(val.toLoweCase().indexOf(search) > -1) {
           flag = true;
           return;
       }
     }
     if(flag) return freight
});
```

Comment: Just a small update you can't toLowerCase() on non-string values, so you should test to make sure you have a string in the if block for the indexOf just to be safe and you have "toLoweCase", it should be "toLowerCase".

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want another code that achieves the same result as the code you posted. Here is mine:

```js
const searchTerm = this.state.search.toLowerCase();

let filteredList = this.state.freights.filter((freight) => {
    // get all keys of freight
    const keys = Object.keys(freight).map(k => k.toLowerCase());
    for (let k of keys) {
      // if key (e.g id) matches the search term, return freight
      if (k.indexOf(searchTerm) !== 1) {
        return true; // we want this freight object
      } 
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the es5 one-liner (sort of):

```js
let filteredList = this.state.freights.filter(freight =>
  Object.keys(freight).some(
    key =>
      freight[key]
        .toLowerCase()
        .indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1,
  ),
);
```