# How to do a search on all values?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to implement search on all values for Angular2. Here is the code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(projects: any, search: any): any {
  if(search === undefined) return projects;

    return projects.filter(function(project)
    {
    return project.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    })

  }

}
```

At the moment it can only search by name, and how to make so that he could look at all the values in the table (for example, id, name, surname, country, etc.)

Comment: is this a single level object? no inner objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
 return projects.filter(function(project)
{
      return project.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      ||
      return project.id.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      ||
      return project.surname.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      ||
      ...
       ;
})
```

or you can look at something like [Array filtering on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713881/array-filtering-on-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 0):

If the object is only 1 level deep you can just go trough all the keys and concatenate all the values before doing the compare.

It would look something like this.

```js
function search(projects, search) {
    return projects.filter(p => {
        return Object
            .keys(p) // get all keys
            .map(k => p[k]) // get all values
            .reduce((prev, current) => prev + current, '') // concat
            .toLowerCase() // lowercase
            .includes(search.toLowerCase()); compare
    });
```

And in pipe form.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(projects: any, search: any): any {
         if(search === undefined) return projects;
         return projects.filter(p => {
            return Object
                .keys(p)
                .map(k => p[k])
                .reduce((prev, current) => prev + current, '')
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(search.toLowerCase());
        });

    }

}
```